# Can't figure out why php script failing on $.ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

Here's my jQuery script:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'zipCodes.php',
data: searchZipCode,
cache: false,
success: function(response) {
    alert ('response from db search: ' + response);
},
error: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert('Query failed, php script returned this response: ' + response);
}
});
```

The above script is in the head tag of the html file the form is in. The php script is in the same folder as the html file.

Here's the form:

```
<form id="frmZipCodeSearch" action="">
    <label for="txtZipCodeSearch">Enter a zip code</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtZipCodeSearch" length="10" maxlength="5" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitZipCodeSearch" />
</form>
```

I also have verified that "searchZipCode" has a value.

Every time I run the search I get the alert from the error part of the ajax call, which says

> Query failed, php script returned this response: [object Object]

and this  shows in the console:

> Object {readyState: 0, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

I've tried stripping the php script down to just an echo. I'm not getting any php error logs generated in the folder with the script on the server. Nothing I change seems to give me a different result. With one exception:

The only time I got a different result was when I stripped out the ajax and moved the php script to the file with the form and did a "regular" html form POST method. That worked. But I don't **think** the path is wrong when the php is a different file because I'm not getting a "file not found" in the console.

What the heck am I missing here?

**[Additional Info]**
In response to hek2mgl's answer, I added xhr to the error response and did get some more info in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: xhr is not defined     zipCodeSearch.html:57
    $.ajax.error                                zipCodeSearch.html:57
    l                                           jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
    c.fireWith                                  jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
    T                                           jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
    r                                           jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
```

All other jQuery I'm using is working fine, but this is the first time I've used v1.8.3 myself.

**[Answer - credit hek2mgl]**
As hek2mgl explained in our crazy-long discussion, I was submitting the form twice, because the ajax call was within the click event of the form's button.

The fix for this was to move the ajax call out of the click event into its own function, and after my client-side validation, call the ajax function and add "return false;" after the function call.

Comment: What do you see when you run your PHP script by itself?

Comment: Instead of `alert ('response from db search: ' + response);`, put `console.log('response from db search: '); console.log(response);` so we can see the actual response.

Comment: @eventide Check my update. I've tested it using jquery-1.8.3.min.js + Firefox (latest) Linux. This gives you the response body of the error. Is  this is what you wanted?

Comment: @hek2mgl - I tried your amended code and in the alert box nothing was after the hardcoded string, and nothing was written to the console. I've tried this in FF and Chrome, latest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $.ajax error callback is defined as follows:

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

You've dumped the whole jqXHR object. Unlike the success function, the respone text itself is not a param of the error callback. To retrieve the response text (if any) use this:

```
error: function(xhr) {
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(response);
    var statusMessage = xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText;
    var message  = 'Query failed, php script returned this status: ';
    var message = message + statusMessage + ' response: ' + response;
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: This gave me a blank message in the alert, after the string and nothing in the console - see my edit in my OP for more info before your edit.

Comment: @eventide Does zipCodes.php return any body on error? or is it a blank page?

Comment: All I currently have in the php script is $zipCode = $_POST['searchZipCode']; echo ('zipcode: ' . $zipCode); I don't seem to be getting anything back.

Comment: @eventide Why is the error function triggered when $zipCodes php just prints the zip code?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, I guess: Why is the error triggering no matter what I do to the php script?

Comment: alert box said: "Query failed, php script returned this status: 0 error response:" Nothing in the console (except the file and line number the console.log line is on).

Comment: @eventide When you inspect the network tab in the firebug console. Can you see which HTTP status code the server returns?

Comment: @eventide Is url really 'zipCodes.php'? Or something like 'http://yourserver.com/path/zipCodes.php' ?

Comment: The php script is in the same folder as the html page, so I assumed the path wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Yes then the path is ok. (I only asked because I thought there could be a cross domain problem).. Now the problem is clear: You got 304 not modified. Meaning that the results of zipCodes.php was cached by the browser. A 304 response has no body and thatswhy responseText is empty. To make sure results of ajax calls will not being cached build the url like this : `'url' : 'zipCodes.php?random=' + Math.random()` this will add a random param to the url, so it won't be cached

Comment: Also you should set the 'Last-Modified' header on PHP site

Comment: How do I do that? ("set the Last-Modified' header on PHP site"). Also, modifying the url parameter didn't change anything - still get the 0 error response in the alert and nothing in the console

Comment: google: [PHP set last modified header](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php+set+last+modified+header&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=Wcf9UKyAFs3LsgaPooG4Aw)

Comment: okay - should've googled that :) I added header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); to the top of the php script, but nothing changed (same error as before)

Comment: have you tried this? `'url' : 'zipCodes.php?random=' + Math.random()`

Comment: Yes - changed the url param to that, as you recommended.

Comment: I really cannot believe that.

Comment: I can send you the files! ;)

Comment: ok, do it. You can post them to pastebin.com and share the link

Comment: Could this have anything to do with PHP version and/or settings on the server? I've never worked on this web host before (client's host).

Comment: Can't share the actual files - for a client on their server. Here's the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/bbQywiwN

Comment: I don't the acutal files. Just a link to the online version of zipCodes.php

Comment: of course - here you go: http://whub32.webhostinghub.com/~forsyt11/zipCodes/zipCodeSearch.html

Comment: Your problem is, that you send the form twice: 1. via ajax, 2. via a regular form submit. You added the $.ajax call to the onclick handler of **a form submit** button. Even when you left the action="" clean, the page will reload. Google : [jquery submitting from with ajax](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=submitting+from+with+ajax+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=6s_9UPKvLNHFtAbI44DIBw). Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Before I ask "How do I fix it" I'm going to try something to see if I've got the solution right.

Comment: Ok, if not I would suggest you to open another question (or search existing ones). This belongs not really to the topic of this question. The answer to this question is as I wrote above.

Comment: I amended my fix to my OP. Thank you **so much**, hek2mgl. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Comment: :) You are welcome! Had this problem once too. I guess that you won't forget this bit anymore.. ;)