# $.AJAX.error l c.fireWith T r error? what is this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447526/cant-figure-out-why-php-script-failing-on-ajax-call) says it occurs when it sends twice.

Mine activates when a user changes the value in a selection box, so this isn't my problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828888/ajax-post-in-using-slim-framework-outputs-500-internal-server-error) is my previous question which shows my code and a few screenshots of the errors.

I couldn't get the 500 (Internal server error) working, hopefully solving the ajax problem first will help sort it out.

The full error from the console:

```
error                                                  admin-add-module:128
    $.ajax.error                                       admin-add-module:128
    l                                                  jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
    c.fireWith                                         jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
    T                                                  jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
    r                                                  jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
```

After changing JQuery to the full version it output this error:

[image]

Comment: you can see more descriptive error if you don't use minifed version of jquery

Comment: Thanks @aacanakin I never knew that! I have posted a screen shot above of the full error

Comment: I think the main problem here is the php code. Internal server error means you have problem in your backend, not jquery

Comment: Yeah, I have had a look at the error logs in Apache and tried lodes of solutions, but nothing seems to work. I was hoping that solving this ajax problem first could help?

Comment: some server error log might be helpful to post

Comment: I posted them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828888/ajax-post-in-using-slim-framework-outputs-500-internal-server-error in the comments section under one of the answers. It says "link undefined" and I don't understand why.. I have defined it in index.php, then used `require_once __DIR__ . '/../index.php';`

Comment: If I then get rid of  all the undefined values it gets rid of the 500 internal error, but still outputs the AJAX error above

Comment: here's the workflow I can suggest. make a post request by restman. try to log the error. solve the backend. after that, you can take a look about this error. Also, I can't help if I don't get to see any code. I'm not sure the problem is same with the previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the 500 internet server error. I wasn't parsing through the link.

```
$app->post('/admin-get-add-module', function () use($app,$link){ <<<<<<<<LINK HERE
    $req = $app->request();
    $stackid = $_POST['stackid'];
    $myStacks = filterStacks($app);
    $app->view()->appendData(array("username" => getUsername($app)));
    $sql = $link->prepare("select * from evironments where StackID=?");
    error_log(var_export($sql,true));
    $sql->bind_param("i", $stackid);
})->name('admin-get-add-module');
```

It still doesn't work though [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845350/sql-query-returns-non-object-using-ajax-jquery-and-slim-framework) is a link to the sql / ajax problem